# Rails Gem: Model Without A Generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I've written a gemified plugin for Rails. At the moment, this plugin requires the user to type `rails generate my_plugin:install` in the console, at which point it generates several models and places them directly in the user's `app/models` directory. This works fine for now, but I see it causing long-term problems if I ever want to change those models. The user will then have to call `rails destroy my_plugin:install` and then generate them all over again.

So is there a way to include the models directly in my gem's lib directory so that the user doesn't have to generate them?

Comment: Rails engines give you that ability.

Comment: That did the trick. For anyone else who needs to make the conversation, there's excellent documentation on Rails Engines [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html).